# deleteRecord(RecordId) in LWC not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I am working on a requirement where I have to delete the record. I have used the standard `deleteRecord` feature of LWC. But the record is not getting deleted. Adding my code below. Please help!

**markup**

```
<lightning-button data-formid={form.Id}  variant="brand" label="Delete" onclick={handleFormData}>
</lightning-button>
```

**JS**

```
    handleFormData(event){
      const selectedRecordId = event.target.dataset.formid;
      console.log('****2',selectedRecordId);
      deleteRecord(selectedRecordId)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('***Delete Success');
          this.dispatchEvent(
              new ShowToastEvent({
                  title: 'Success',
                  message: 'Record deleted successfully',
                  variant: 'success'
              }),
              window.location.reload()
          );
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.log('**error**',error);
      });
   }
```

I am getting the `selectedRecordId` in the console log. But `console.log('***Delete Success')` is not getting populated.

Comment: if success is not printed in the console, does it mean, that error is printed to the console  `console.log('**error**',error);`? please provide your console log.

Comment: Oleksandr Berehovskyi, Error is also not getting printed.

Comment: strange, can you remove this `window.location.reload()` and try to see, we should get atleast one state.

Comment: Is you flow entering into the .then or .error blocks? Are you able to see ***error** ?

Comment: @AvneshShakya I have removed 'window.location.reload()' , still the result is same.

Comment: @LoveBomber777, not error message.

Comment: how are you importing deleteRecord ?

Comment: did you import it `import { deleteRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';`

Comment: @SFDC44 did you issue resolve?

Comment: yes, @AvneshShakya.. thank you.